# PROBLEMS Making a Search Page PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, dropdown

I'm facing an issue most probably due to my lack of experience.

I'm getting the data successfully from the MYSQL DATABASE and it is successfully populating the Second DROPDOWN menu.

The problem is... when I click in "Validate" to submit and record the data in the variable it cleans the previous option selected. I'm being unable to record the selected options in variables.

```
<?php
$location = "";
$locationf = "";
$system = "";
$systemf = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'test', 'SRSBASE')
        or die('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("select distinct SUB_ACCOUNT from SRSLOAD");

if (isset($_POST["selec"]["account"])) {
    $location = $_POST["selec"]["account"];
    $locationf = $location;
    $locationf = sprintf('%s', $locationf);
}

echo "Location: $locationf";

$conn2 = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'test', 'SRSBASE')
        or die('Cannot connect to db');

$result2 = $conn2->query("select distinct SYSTEMNAME from SRSLOAD where SUB_ACCOUNT='$locationf'");

if (isset($_POST["selec"]["system"])) {
    $system = $_POST["selec"]["system"];
    $systemf = $system;
}

echo "System: $systemf";

$post_at = "";
$post_at_to_date = "";
$post_at_todate = "";

$queryCondition = "";
if (!empty($_POST["search"]["post_at"])) {
    $post_at = $_POST["search"]["post_at"];
    list($fiy, $fim, $fid) = explode("-", $post_at);

    $post_at_todate = date('YY-mm-dd');
    if (!empty($_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"])) {
        $post_at_to_date = $_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"];
        list($tiy, $tim, $tid) = explode("-", $_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"]);
        $post_at_todate = "$tiy-$tim-$tid";

    //TESTING SELECTED TARGETS
    //echo $post_at;
    //echo "/";
    //echo $post_at_todate;
    }

    //$queryCondition .= "WHERE RDATE BETWEEN '$fiy-$fim-$fid' AND '" . $post_at_todate . "'";
    $queryCondition .= "WHERE RDATE BETWEEN '$post_at' AND '" . $post_at_todate . "'";
}

//$sql = "SELECT * from SRSLOAD " . $queryCondition . " ORDER BY post_at desc";
//$sql = "select * from SRSLOAD where rdate between '$post_at' AND $post_at_todate;"

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM SRSLOAD WHERE RDATE BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' AND SYSTEMNAME='%s' AND SUB_ACCOUNT='%s'", $post_at, $post_at_todate, $systemf, $locationf);

$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Storage Report System - Search</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.4.css">

        <style>
            .table-content{border-top:#CCCCCC 4px solid; width:50%;}
            .table-content th {padding:5px 20px; background: #F0F0F0;vertical-align:top;}
            .table-content td {padding:5px 20px; border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px solid;vertical-align:top;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2 style='font-family:arial'>Storage Report System - Search</h2>

        <form name='sname' id='sname' action='' method='POST'>
            <select id='select' name="selec[account]" value="<?php echo $location; ?>" >
                <option value='-1'>--Select the Location--</option>

                <?php
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    unset($sub_acc);
                    $sub_acc = $row['SUB_ACCOUNT'];
                    echo '<option value="' . $sub_acc . '">' . $sub_acc . '</option>';
                }
                ?>

            </select>
            <input type='submit' value='Validate' />
        </form>

        <form name='sname' id='sname' action='' method='POST' >
            <select id='system' name="selec[system]" value="<?php echo $system; ?>" >

                <option value='-1'>--Select the System--</option>
                <?php
                while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

                    unset($syst);
                    $syst = $row2['SYSTEMNAME'];
                    echo '<option value="' . $syst . '">' . $syst . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type='submit' value='Validate' />
        </form>

        <div class="demo-content">
            <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
                <p class="search_input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="post_at" name="search[post_at]" value="<?php echo $post_at; ?>" class="input-control" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="post_at_to_date" name="search[post_at_to_date]" style="margin-left:10px" value="<?php echo $post_at_to_date; ?>" class="input-control" />
                    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Search" >
                </p>
                <?php if (!empty($result3)) { ?>
                    <table class="table-content">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="30%"><span>SYSTEM NAME</span></th>
                                <th width="50%"><span>DATE</span></th>
                                <th width="20%"><span>HSM</span></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["SYSTEMNAME"]; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["RDATE"]; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["HSM_MCDS"]; ?></td>

                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        <tbody>
                    </table>
                <?php } ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.datepicker.setDefaults({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
                buttonText: "Date Picker",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
            $(function () {
                $("#post_at").datepicker();
                $("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have two forms there. Every form has its own select and submit. When you click submit, only appropriate form with select is sent.
When you want to have data from both selects, you have to have both selects in one form with one submit.
Something like this code:

```
<form name='sname' id='sname' action='' method='POST'>
    <select id='select' name="selec[account]" value="<?php echo $location; ?>" >
        <option value='-1'>--Select the Location--</option>
        <?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            unset($sub_acc);
            $sub_acc = $row['SUB_ACCOUNT'];
            echo '<option value="' . $sub_acc . '">' . $sub_acc . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <select id='system' name="selec[system]" value="<?php echo $system; ?>" >
        <option value='-1'>--Select the System--</option>
        <?php
        while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            unset($syst);
            $syst = $row2['SYSTEMNAME'];
            echo '<option value="' . $syst . '">' . $syst . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Validate' />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi von Oak,

Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I would need the first submit to populate the second Dropdown menu.

So knowing about this restriction I can think in two solutions:

1- Build a html file and a php file for each dropdown menu (some ideas but not sure how to do).

2- Use a language that allow me to pickup the value in a php variable without submitting but only selecting. (most likely, but I don't have much idea about how to do)

Comment: I don't understand exactly your use case. Why you need to populate the second menu first and so on? What is the use case? With more info, I am maybe able to suggest something further.

Comment: Sure, let me clarify: I'm building a simple "search page". For this I would need 4 information, 1- The server name, 2- The Location, 3- The initial date, 4- the final date. I would bring to the users some utilization samples from a database.

When I submit the first Dropdown select, it is bringing all systems from certain location. I should reserve the system in a variable, the location in another variable, then the dates so I would make a final MYSQL select to provide the answer to the user.

Comment: Ok, then simple solution is to make html and php file for each dropdown menu, as you propose in point 1). The more difficult but also more user friendly solution is via [AJAX (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), [AJAX (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)